# Is it possible to have a read-only MongoDB-instance on a database folder that already is used on another server?

Tags: mongodb, shared-storage

I have the following setup:

— Many servers

— One shared network mounted data storage folder

On one of the servers, I need to run MongoDB to write data to it. I want to be able to access those written data from other servers while the one instance is still running. Is it possible to have a read-only-instance of MongoDB that allows this? In all others, I don't need to write anything, just read.

Comment: Why not replication then ? You would be able to access data on any of the servers this way. Doesn't look like you need a shared storage.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share a `dbPath` with multiple active `mongod` processes - each process requires exclusive access to the data files.

For data redundancy and readonly copies of data, MongoDB supports [replica set deployments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/). A replica set [elects a single primary member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) that accepts writes and can have multiple read-only secondary members. By default all reads and writes are directed to the current primary in a replica set, but your driver or application can use [read preferences](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) to read from secondary members. In the event the current primary is unavailable, replica sets also support failover based on your configuration.

However, shared storage is not ideal for a replica set as you will be writing many copies of the same data to the shared storage (which presumably also has some built-in write redundancy).

With or without replication, you should configure MongoDB's [Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authorization/) so that your applications authenticate with appropriate privileges such as read-only access. The [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) has a list of security measures to consider. Even if access is limited to a trusted network, use of RBAC limits your exposure to accidental data modification and provides some audit trail in the MongoDB server logs.